# How to convert the text of qml a textField to float and int

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I tried to pass a value inserted in textField in a C++ `float` variable.

The following code is a representation of what I need.

```
TextField{id:textField1}
Button{onClicked:function.printFloat = textField1.text.toFloat}
```

but I received the following warning message:

```
qrc:/qml/window/WindowConfigTelemetry.qml:215: Error: Cannot assign QString to float
```

What is wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit hard with some parts of your code missing, but you can use the Javascript function `parseInt` and `parseFloat`

```
console.log("integer: ", parseInt(textField1.text))
console.log("float: ", parseFloat(textField1.text))
```

See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-functionlist.html for more helpful functions

Comment: I made some tries and surprisingly parseFloat return a double precision number